# My program is closes as soon as it opens in Python 3.8.8 (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, pyinstaller, spyder

I have created a small GUI program using tkinter (Python 3.8.8) however when I create an .exe file using this command in the cmd : pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py. It does create the executable file however when I click this .exe file, it close the program as soon as it start to executes. To resolve that issue I have tried the following:

1. I have put Input("Enter any key to end") in the end of the code.
2. I have run the command without using --onefile in CMD.

It does not show any error in the console. When I run my code in spyder IDE, It does not cause any issue.

Please guide me how do I configure that .exe file to not to close the program.

```
def click():
   df = pd.read_csv("meta.csv")
   State = df["State"]
# Ask for the directory where you want to save the file
   paths = askdirectory(title='Select Folder')
   print(paths)

   dt = datetime.now()

# Mapping of TextBox
   entered_text = txtSurName.get()

# Final file name format will be like: DateTime+Surname.csv
   dt_res = dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y%H%M%S%f")
   dt_res = "/"+ dt_res + entered_text +".csv"   
   dic = {'state' : State}
   df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
   df.to_csv(paths+dt_res)

    



window = Tk()
window.configure(background="black")


# Labels and their value assigment 
Label(window, text="Enter Surname ", bg="black",fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W);
txtSurName = Entry(window, width=50, bg="white");
txtSurName.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W);

# Button
Button(window, text="Submit" , width = 6, command=click).grid(row=6,column=0,sticky=W);

#GUI LOGIC
window.mainloop()
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Please provide a [example]. This code _does_ show error messages. First, there are indentation problems that will cause `SyntaxError`s. Second, there are no imports, so we have to guess what you have imported.  Are you sure that none of this is causing your `exe` to close?

Comment: does running the `exe` raise any errors? otherwise makes no sense for it not to execute properly. run the `exe` from the `cmd` and see if you get any exceptions or errors

Comment: After adding the required `import` lines and create the executable using `PyInstaller` 4.7 under Python 3.8.12 in Windows 7, the mentioned issue cannot be reproduced when the generated executable is executed.

Comment: Which modules have you imported? Also, does the program work in ```.py``` form? When I try to run your program as exe, it works without any problems.

Comment: There is no indentation problems in my .py code and I imported the following: 
from tkinter  import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory